# Placing TIF image on top of WMS layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms, geotiff-tiff

How to place TIF file on the top of WMS layer in QGIS?

When I import TIF file, it has different coordinate system, and it is placed far from WMS layer, but I want to put this TIF layer on the top of WMS layer.

I know how to make them transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the coordinate system of the TIF file, you can choose it with Rightclick on the layer entry -> `Set CRS for layer`.

Make sure `On-the-fly-reprojection` is activated in Settings -> Project Settings

If you don't know the correct coordinate system, you have to georeference the TIF file with the georeferencer plugin. You can use points in the WMS as refrence, but then you have to set the CRS of the TIF to the same as the WMS.